# Restricting values in type constructors

Tags: haskell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a type bounded within a certain range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302735/how-to-create-a-type-bounded-within-a-certain-range)

I have the data type:

```
data Expr = Num Int
          | Expression Expr Operator Expr
```

In the context of the problem, the numbers that `(Num Int)` will represent are single digit only. Is there a way to ensure that restriction within the type declaration?

Of course we could define a function to test whether the `Expr` is valid, but it would be nice to have the type system handle it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use an abstract data type with a *[smart constructor](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Smart_constructors)*:

```
newtype Digit = Digit { digitVal :: Int }
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

mkDigit :: Int -> Maybe Digit
mkDigit n
  | n >= 0 && n < 10 = Just (Digit n)
  | otherwise = Nothing
```

If you put this in another module and don't export the `Digit` constructor, then client code can't construct values of type `Digit` outside of the range [0,9], but you have to manually wrap and unwrap it to use it. You could define a `Num` instance that does modular arithmetic, if that would be helpful; that would also let you use numeric literals to construct Digits. (Similarly for `Enum` and `Bounded`.)

However, this doesn't ensure that you never *try* to create an invalid Digit, just that you never *do*. If you want more assurance, then the manual solution Jan offers is better, at the cost of being less convenient. (And if you define a `Num` instance for that Digit type, it will end up just as "unsafe", because you'd be able to write `42 :: Digit` thanks to the numeric literal support you'd get.)

(If you don't know what `newtype` is, it's basically `data` for data-types with a single, strict field; a newtype wrapper around *T* will have the same runtime representation as *T*. It's basically just an optimisation, so you can pretend it says `data` for the purpose of understanding this.)

**Edit:** For the more theory-oriented, 100% solution, see the rather cramped comment section of this answer.

Comment: That would do the job, but the type system isn't what is handling the problem. That is more what I am going for.

Comment: Right — the additional assurance here is that no value of type `Digit` can be invalid, as opposed to simply validating an `Expr` after-the-fact. Note that even the manual enumeration solution permits values such as `error "oops" :: Digit`. There are ways to handle these things strongly and conveniently in advanced type systems, but they haven't made their way into Haskell yet, so a compromise like this is likely to be the best solution. (Not that they've made it into any other "real-world" language, either.)

Comment: If the type system were handling the problem, I wouldn't have to validate the `Expr` because it wouldn't compile in the first place, right?

Comment: Indeed; I was just tying it into your reference to validating `Expr` in the question. If you have a data type containing a `Digit`, you don't have to check it: any value it has will contain an `Int` from 0 to 10. It's just that *constructing* a `Digit` has the possibility for error, which would manifest in an exception when the `Digit` field is evaluated (due to laziness). You may find `mkDigit :: Int -> Maybe Digit` more appealing, as it forces invalid digits to be handled up-front at the point of construction.

Comment: But that wouldn't be caught at compile time, right?

Comment: Well, you can't catch everything at compile time; if you ask a user for a number between 1 and 9, and they enter 8192, you have to perform a runtime check. The advantage of a wrapper type like this is that you can write code operating on Exprs knowing for a fact that any Digit fields will contain a valid integer between 0 and 9; converting an arbitrary integer value to a Digit is separated out into the smart constructor for Digit. At compile-time, you can be guaranteed that no Digit contains an integer greater than 10; that's why you don't export the constructor from the module.

Comment: I've converted the `mkDigit` example in my answer to use `Maybe`, as it's more obviously the correct choice for a situation like this. Anyway, you presumably parse a string into an Expr at some point, which means validating that the digit involved is between 0 and 9. `mkDigit` makes that check mandatory: there is no way to create a Digit without going through it, and thus ensuring that the Int truly is a single digit.

Comment: So, the answer to the question is "No"? (I am familiar with smart constructors, by the way.)
Thanks for the conversation.

Comment: Well, it's "yes, but it's far more awkward than going half-way". :) I would personally say that this solution enforces the invariant with statically with the type system, since it lets you guarantee that a value of Digit is valid, which is the essence of strong static typing to me. YMMV.

Comment: If there is a way, then how would one actually solve this with the type system? I am curious more than anything. Any resources on the topic? I can't find anything, hence the post.

Comment: With [generalised abstract data types](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Generalised_algebraic_datatype) and [phantom types](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Phantom_type) to provide [type-level natural numbers](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Type_arithmetic), you can construct the type of natural numbers smaller than some type-level natural `n`: `data Fin n where { Fz :: Fin (S n); Fs :: Fin n -> Fin (S n) }` — unfortunately I am rapidly exhausting this margin, so that's about the best I can do in this medium :)

Comment: It's a fair question, certainly, I just interpreted yours as more practically-oriented. This kind of stuff is pretty awkward in practice; you'd want a real dependently-typed language like Agda to do it neatly. Or at least [Omega](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A9mega) ([2](http://code.google.com/p/omega/), [3](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/4088)).

Comment: No problem :) Good timing, too: [inch](https://github.com/adamgundry/inch) was just posted to [/r/haskell](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell), and it sets out to achieve exactly this, but with additional sugar layered on top to make it convenient.

Answer (score 7):

Since there are only ten possibilities, you could use `Enum` to specify all of them.

```
data Digit = Zero | One | Two deriving (Enum, Show)
```

Then you'd have to use `fromEnum` to treat them as numbers.

```
1 == fromEnum One
```

Similarly, using `toEnum` you can get a `Digit` from a number.

```
toEnum 2 :: Digit
```

We can go even further and implement `Num`.

```
data Digit = Zero | One | Two deriving (Enum, Show, Eq)

instance Num Digit where
  fromInteger x = toEnum (fromInteger x) :: Digit
  x + y = toEnum $ fromEnum x + fromEnum y
  x * y = toEnum $ fromEnum x * fromEnum y
  abs = id
  signum _ = 1

Zero + 1 + One == Two
```