# create a Haskell type with finitely many inhabitants

Tags: haskell, types

According to “Haskell for a great good”, the type declaration for Bool is

```
data Bool = True | False
```

and that the type declaration for Int may be considered something like

```
data Int = -2147483648 | -2147483647 | ... | -1 | 0 | 1 | 2 | ... | 2147483647
```

For some abstract algebra applications, I would like to create an analogous type with finitely many specified values, for example the values may be integers between $0$ and $n$, for some $n$. Despite the claimed definition of Int, the following doesn’t work:

```
data F3 = 0 | 1 | 2
```

with error "Illegal literal in type”. How can I create a type where these are the only inhabitants? Something like:

```
data F a = (Int a) => [0..a]
```

would be totally awesome.

Also, can I create a function that enumerates all the valid values of a type, or returns a list of values?

Comment: That example declaration for `Int` takes place in a theoretical world where the `Int` type has not been defined and therefore the "symbols" of the numbers don't have meaning yet. It doesn't work in reality because, in reality, the `Int` type does exist and those numbers have a meaning, so they can't be used as value constructors.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart: Is there any way I can clear those definitions for Int and then declare the numbers $0$ through $n$ for my own use?

Comment: There is no way in Haskell to remove numeric literals from the language. I think you might find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302735/how-to-create-a-type-bounded-within-a-certain-range) relevant.

Comment: I think for something like your last example, you are looking for dependent types, which don't exist in Haskell. Dependent types are types that depend on values. We only have fake dependent types in Haskell (at the moment). In dependent type systems, your last example is sometimes called `Fin`, for "finite".

Comment: @Chuck: That example discussed in your link, where a type is defined using Peano arithmetic taking values in a range is probably what I want. Except that is pretty restricted. It only allows to create a type restricted to a range of natural numbers, whereas I will eventually want to create a type with values restricted to an arbitrary set.

Comment: @DavidYoung: dependent type because the type depends on $a$? Is a dependent type different than a type constructor that takes a type argument?

Comment: @JoeHannon Well, as it is, your example is not dependent because `a` is a *type* argument and not a *value* argument (it wouldn't really be possible for a type to have a value argument in Haskell because it doesn't have real dependent types). I suspect that a dependent type is closer to what you had in mind though. You can kinda fake it in Haskell, but I'm not sure if you can do that particular thing (a finite type parametrized on a "value"). I feel like I've seen someone do it, hmm. I'd have to think about it. It would probably involve some sorta advanced type stuff though.

Answer (score 10):

You can use nullary constructors (like `True`, `False`, `Nothing`, `()` etc)

```
data F3 = Zero | One | Two
    deriving (Bounded, Enum, Show)
```

To enumerate all valid values, we simply derive `Enum` and `Bounded` and let GHC do all the work for us.

```
enum :: (Bounded a, Enum a) => [a]
enum = [minBound .. maxBound]

λ. enum :: [F3]
[Zero,One,Two]
```

If you want to use these like actual `Int`, you can use `fromEnum :: Enum a => a -> Int` which will be equivalent to

```
fromEnum Zero = 0
fromEnum One  = 1
fromEnum Two  = 2
```

Comment: Worth noting that you can (abusively) get actual numeric literals with `instance Num F3 where {fromInteger = toEnum . flip mod 3}`

Comment: @jozefg, that does not seem abusive to me, esp if the other `Num` methods are defined.

Answer (score 5):

You can't use integer literals in a new type like that. They are already taken, so it isn't valid syntax.

cdk's answer gives a much more practical scenario, but I thought I would give an example of how something like your last example could be implemented in Haskell.

If we turn on some of the more fun extensions, we can convince GHC to make a type with a given finite number of values. I probably wouldn't suggest *actually doing this* in real code, however, because GHC doesn't have the best support for this kind of dependent type-like programming at the moment.  Also, unfortunately, the values don't have nice names. As far as I know, there isn't a way to give them nice names like `1, 2, 3...` (edit: actually, we *can* improve on this a little bit, see the second code block).

It could go something like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds, KindSignatures, TypeOperators #-}

module Fin (Fin (..))
  where

import GHC.TypeLits -- We get Nat from here as well as the type-level `<=` and `+`.

-- This is a type parameterized by another type. The type that parameterizes (`Nat`)
-- behaves like natural numbers at a type level. The `Nat -> *` is the "kind" of the type
-- `Fin`. A kind is like a type for types. To put it another way, a kind is to a type what
-- a type is to a value. In this case, the type `Nat` has kind `Nat`.
data Fin :: Nat -> * where
  FZero :: Fin upperBound
  FSucc :: (1 <= upperBound) => Fin upperBound -> Fin (upperBound + 1)

-- This is ok, because we are using the "fourth" value in a type with five values.
fifthValue :: Fin 5
fifthValue = FSucc (FSucc (FSucc FZero))

-- This doesn't compile, because it tries to make something of type
-- `Fin 2` using a "3rd value".
--    thirdValue :: Fin 2
--    thirdValue = FSucc (FSucc FZero)
--
-- The only inhabitants of `FiniteList 2` are `FZero` and `FSucc FZero`
```

Note that to actually get instances for things like `Eq` and `Ord` you might have to do even more tricky things (I'm not even totally sure if it's possible. It might need the new type level natural number theorem prover that they're putting in GHC 7.10).

One other thing I should probably point out is that the types that inhabit the kind `Nat` are named `1, 2, ...`. This is ok because there isn't anything else that use those names at a type level (just at a value level).

Edit:

If we turn on a couple more extensions, we can get a version where you can (almost) directly specify the names of the values:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures, GADTs, TypeOperators, PolyKinds, TypeFamilies, UndecidableInstances #-}
import Data.Type.Equality
import GHC.TypeLits

type family (||) (a :: Bool) (b :: Bool) :: Bool where
  True  || x  = True
  False || x  = x

type family Elem (a :: k) (xs :: [k]) :: Bool where
  Elem x (y ': ys) = (x == y) || Elem x ys
  Elem x '[]       = False


data NamedFin :: [k] -> * where
  Val :: ((a `Elem` as) ~ True) => Proxy a -> NamedFin as

-- Countdown n makes a type level list of Nats.
-- So, for example, Countdown 3 is a shorthand for '[3, 2, 1]
type family Countdown (a :: Nat) :: [Nat] where
  Countdown 0 = '[]
  Countdown n = (n - 1) ': Countdown (n - 1)

data Proxy a = Proxy deriving Show

type Example = NamedFin (Countdown 5) -- This is the same as NamedFin '[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

-- This compiles...
example :: Example
example = Val (Proxy :: Proxy 4)

-- ...but this doesn't
--     example2 :: Example
--     example2 = Val (Proxy :: Proxy 10)
```

There will still be issues making instances for `Eq` and `Ord` though.

Comment: I'd recommend the [modular-arithmetic](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/modular-arithmetic) package for this kind of finite types.