# Haskell multiple conditions combined

Tags: function, haskell, if-statement, conditional-statements

I've been looking for a while now and didn't find any answers to my question. 
I tried to write a function that returns the days of a specific month depending on whether it is in a lap year or not. I already defined the function "lapyear" previously. My question is how can I create an If condition within another If condition ?

Thank you a lot for your answers :)

```
lapyear:: Int->Bool
lapyear a
    |((rem)a 400)==0 = True
    |((rem)a 100)==0 = False
    |((rem)a 4)==0 = True
    |otherwise = False

type Mes = Int
type Anyo = Int
type Dias= Int
daysAmonth:: Mes->Anyo->Dias
daysAmonth mes anyo
if lapyear anyo then do
    |or[mes==01,mes==03,mes==05,mes==07,mes==08,mes==10,mes==12] = 31
    |mes==02 = 29
    |otherwise = 30
else
    |or[mes==01,mes==03,mes==05,mes==07,mes==08,mes==10,mes==12] = 31
    |mes==02 = 28
    |otherwise = 30
```

Comment: `if <cond1> then if <cond2> then x1 else x2 else x3`? Or you may be interested in the [`MultiWayIf`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.1/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#multi-way-if) extension of GHC.

Comment: Anyway the code seems wrong. You have `mes == [01, 03, ..]` and then `mes == 02`.  But it's unlikely that lists are `Num` instances, so this would probably raise a type error.

Comment: I would like the program to first check the condition of lapyear anyo and depending on that go on to the three other conditions

Comment: To make your ifs a little clearer, consider using the Haskell typing system to define your Mes as a data type instead of an Int:
    data Mes = enero | febrero | marzo | ... | noviembre | diciembre

Also consider bounding your Dias data type, as suggested in:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302735/how-to-create-a-type-bounded-within-a-certain-range

Comment: On an unrelated note you may want to rewrite lapyear [like so](http://lpaste.net/144566)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might like the [`MultiWayIf`](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/guide-to-ghc-extensions/basic-syntax-extensions#multiwayif) extension.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiWayIf #-}

if lapyear anyo then if
    | or [...] -> 31
    | mes == 20 -> 29
    | otherwise -> 30
else if
    | ...
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this will work but now an error appears that says "Multi-way if-expressions need MultiWayIf turned on". How do I import multiwayif ?

Comment: It's working now, I only had to multiwayif via     :set -XMultiWayIf   thank you again

Comment: Note the `{-# LANGUAGE MultiWayIf #-}`.  If you put that at the very top of your file, you don't need a command-line flag.

Answer (score 1):

Some alternatives in plain Haskell (without extensions):

- chain of `if then else`:

  ```
  if lapyear anyo then
     if or [...] then 31
     else if mes == 02 then 29
     else 30
  else ...
  ```
- using `let`:

  ```
  if lapyear anyo then
     let result | or [...]  = 31
                | mes == 02 = 29
                | otherwise = 30
          in result
  else ...
  ```
- using `case`:

  ```
  if lapyear anyo then
     case () of
     _ | or [...]  -> 31
       | mes == 02 -> 29
       | otherwise -> 30
  else ...
  ```

I believe the last one is the most popular.

Comment: Seems like the easiest way to me without having to import anything. Thank you!